# Automatically authorize oAuth on Linkedin authorization page

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I already have oAuth working with the Linked API. The dance is working nicely. But now I have the Linkedin data displaying correctly on my site I'm now thinking about throttle limits and load speeds.

I don't want the site to keep requesting throughout the day. It would be better if I could run a script via cron every 6 hours to make the requests all at once. (There will be less than 3000 requests each time.) This will make my pages load faster and my site wont have to wait for the API callbacks in order to display the full page.

**Headache** = When using the Linkedin API all calls have to be authenticated. Users do this manually once per session but how can I script this process? Is there a direct way to send *my?* details to linkedin to autorize before the script carries on making requests?

---

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

My setup uses:

- OAuth.php http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/
- Linkedinclass.php http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/

Comment: As Mark S mentioned, on initial user authentication store their access token and then you can make any needed REST calls anytime you need to.

Comment: +1 b/c of the class that you chose.  I have been looking for a simple linkedin class for quite some time and this one seems to be living up to it's name.

Comment: @ServAce85 thanks - glad this helped you. I later moved this over to start using the oAuth module in Zend_Framework http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html which is also pretty good (if you're already using ZF)

Comment: Bear in mind that according to the LinkedIn Platform Guidelines and Terms of Use, you're not allowed to store any data from the LinkedIn API on your server: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-platform-guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do the calls need to be authenticated once per session? I haven't seen anything in the LinkedIn API to suggest that you need to authenticate more than once.

With OAuth, it should only need to be authorized once, you store the Access Token and then you use the stored tokens from then on to access the data.

Comment: Ahhh of course! That makes total sense. Thank you for joining the dots :)